# Replace files using adb command

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am able to push the files in the directory using adb command. But when I do it for the second time, it works weird.
For eg.,

```
adb push Tutorial/ sdcard/Docs/
```

Above command works fine for the first time. But when executed for the second time, it executes fine but it is pushing folder again inside Docs.

> 1. sdcard/Docs (First execution)
> 2. sdcard/Docs/Tutorial (Second execution is not replacing the files instead it is creating a new folder inside Docs which is Tutorial)

Though I can check whether the folder exists before pushing it but I would like to replace the files everytime.

Answer (score 2):

adb replace the `file/folder` if any `file/fodler` with the same name exists. you are trying to push folder that's why it is creating a tutorial folder.

If you have files in tutorial folder that you want to push in docs folder

> Inside tutorial folder -> **adb push filename sdcard/docs/**

and if you want to push the tutorial folder inside docs

> Outside tutorial folder -> **adb push tutorial sdcard/docs/**